# Get current cursor lower left position so that tooltip could be displayed properly

Tags: c#, mouse, position

I'm trying to display the tooltip by calling "ToolTip.Show(String, IWin32Window, Point)", but I wanted to do it like what Windows explorer does - displays the tooltip at the lower left corner of the cursor.

I could get the mouse position by "MousePosition", but how could I get its lower left corner position?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If nobody comes up with a better answer you can try this:

```
    toolTip1.Show("Am I where you want me to be?", this, this.PointToClient(MousePosition).X,
                                                         this.PointToClient(MousePosition).Y + Cursor.Size.Height * 2);
```

Adjust the text positioning by playing with the x/y parameters.  It works on my machine but I'm not sure how it would look under different settings.

ToolTip fun tip:  put this line in your Form's MouseMove event.

Comment: Thanks,

Actually I just found out that Cursor.Size.Height could be used. But why mutiply it by 2?

Will it scales with custom cursor?

Comment: I'm not sure why multipling by two works.  I checked into what exactly the Cursor.Size property is (and how it relates to a user's local settings) and sort of gave up when the answer didn't come up on my first few attempts.  This is why I added my warning that the code might not work on all machines!

Answer (score 1):

I think Explorer puts the tooltip under the cursor's hotspot so you don't have to correct the X-position.  This looked good:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  int x = e.X;
  int y = e.Y + Cursor.Current.Size.Height - Cursor.Current.HotSpot.Y;
  toolTip1.Show("test", panel1, x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to scan the cursors MASK and find the distance between the last set pixel in the cursor mask and the cursors Y hotspot, I had to do this up today, so heres the code:

```
#define useUnsafe

using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Utils
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides extension methods for the Cursor class
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>By Aaron Murgatroyd</remarks>
    public static class CursorExtensionMethods
    {
        #region API Functions

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the icon information for a Windows API icon
        /// </summary>
        private struct IconInfo
        {
            public bool fIcon;
            public int xHotspot;
            public int yHotspot;
            public IntPtr hbmMask;
            public IntPtr hbmColor;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the icon information for a Windows API icon
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hIcon">The icon to get the info for</param>
        /// <param name="pIconInfo">The object to receive the info</param>
        /// <returns>True on success, false on failure</returns>
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool GetIconInfo(IntPtr hIcon, ref IconInfo pIconInfo);

        [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
        static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);

        #endregion

        #region Private Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Scans bits in bitmap data for a set or unset bit
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="byteData">The pointer to the first byte of the first scanline</param>
        /// <param name="start">The vertical position to start the scan</param>
        /// <param name="lineInc">The number of bytes to move per line</param>
        /// <param name="maxLines">The number of lines to scan</param>
        /// <param name="set">True to scan for set bits, false to scan for unset bits</param>
        /// <param name="fromBottom">True to scan from the bottom of the bitmap, false to scan from the top</param>
        /// <returns>The number of lines scanned before a bit was found, or -1 if none found before reaching max lines</returns>
#if useUnsafe
        private static unsafe int ScanBits(IntPtr byteData, int start, int lineInc, int maxLines, bool set, bool fromBottom)
#else
        private static int ScanBits(IntPtr byteData, int start, int lineInc, int maxLines, bool set, bool fromBottom)
#endif
        {
            // Calculate the starting byte of the first scanline
#if useUnsafe
            byte* lbLine = ((byte*)byteData) + (start * lineInc);
#else
            int lbLine = ((int)(byteData) + (start * lineInc));
#endif

            int liLine = 0;

            // Use lineInc to determines bytes per line
            int liBytesPerLine = (lineInc < 0 ? -lineInc : lineInc);

            // If we want to search in reverse order
            if (fromBottom)
            {
                // Move to the START of the line
                lbLine += lineInc * (maxLines - 1);

                // Negate the line increment
                lineInc = -lineInc;
            }

            while (maxLines > 0)
            {
                // Setup the line scan
#if useUnsafe
                byte* lbData = lbLine;
#else
                int lbData = lbLine;
#endif
                int liByte = liBytesPerLine;

                // For each byte in the line
                while (liByte > 0)
                {
#if !useUnsafe
                    byte lbByte = Marshal.ReadByte((IntPtr)lbData);
#endif

                    // If we want set bits, and a bit is set
#if useUnsafe
                    if (set && *lbData != 0)
#else
                    if (set && lbByte != 0)
#endif
                        // Return the line number
                        return liLine;
                    else
                        // If we want unset bits and any bits arent set
#if useUnsafe
                        if (!set && *lbData != byte.MaxValue)
#else
                        if (!set && lbByte != byte.MaxValue)
#endif
                            // Return the line number
                            return liLine;

                    // Next byte for scan line
                    liByte--;
                    lbData++;
                }

                // Next scan line
                liLine++;
                maxLines--;
                lbLine += lineInc;
            }

            // If all lines were scanned, return -1
            if (maxLines == 0)
                return -1;
            else
                // Return number of lines scanned
                return liLine;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the number of pixels between the Y hotspot 
        /// and the last physical line of a cursor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cursor">The cursor to scan</param>
        /// <returns>
        /// The number of lines between the Y hotspot
        /// and the last physical line of the cursor
        /// </returns>
        public static int GetBaseLineHeight(this Cursor cursor)
        {
            return GetBaseLine(cursor) - cursor.HotSpot.Y;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the physical base line of the cursor, that is,
        /// the distance between the top of the virtual cursor
        /// and the physical base line of the cursor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="cursor">The cursor to scan</param>
        /// <returns>The number of lines between the top of the virtual cursor 
        /// and the physical base line of the curosr</returns>
        public static int GetBaseLine(this Cursor cursor)
        {
            IconInfo liiInfo = new IconInfo();

            if (!GetIconInfo(cursor.Handle, ref liiInfo))
                return cursor.Size.Height;

            Bitmap lbmpBitmap = Bitmap.FromHbitmap(liiInfo.hbmMask);

            try
            {
                BitmapData lbdData = lbmpBitmap.LockBits(
                    new Rectangle(0, 0, lbmpBitmap.Width, lbmpBitmap.Height),
                    ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed);

                try
                {
                    // Calculate number of lines in AND scan before any found
                    int liLine = ScanBits(lbdData.Scan0, 0, lbdData.Stride, cursor.Size.Height, false, true);

                    // If no AND scan bits found then scan for XOR bits
                    if (liLine == -1 && lbdData.Height == cursor.Size.Height * 2)
                        liLine = ScanBits(lbdData.Scan0, cursor.Size.Height, lbdData.Stride, cursor.Size.Height, true, true);

                    return cursor.Size.Height-liLine;
                }
                finally
                {
                    lbmpBitmap.UnlockBits(lbdData);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                DeleteObject(liiInfo.hbmMask);
                DeleteObject(liiInfo.hbmColor);
                lbmpBitmap.Dispose();
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

You can undefine the conditional define "useUnsafe" at the top so you dont have to enable unsafe code if you like, but be warned it will run slower in this mode.

So this uses extension methods, so all you have to do is add Cursor.Current.GetBaseLineHeight() to your Cursor.Position.Y and that will be the first blank line under the cursor.

ie.

```
Point lptBlankLineUnderCursor = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + Cursor.Current.GetBaseLineHeight())
```