# How to get toolTip on CursorPosition not on MousePosition?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tooltip

im working on code-editor (windows forms application) and I just want to ask how to get tooltip position instead of mouseposition will make it on cursor something like this 1:

[Get current cursor lower left position so that tooltip could be displayed properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746046/get-current-cursor-lower-left-position-so-that-tooltip-could-be-displayed-proper)

specifically this code:

```
private void panel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
  int x = e.X;
  int y = e.Y + Cursor.Current.Size.Height - Cursor.Current.HotSpot.Y;
  toolTip1.Show("test", panel1, x, y);
}
```

but i dont have panel i only got richtextbox[rtb](serve as code editor) and a labelbox[lb](serve as contexthint) .

anyone pls? really in need thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing panel1 to richtextbox[rtb] etc?

Comment: @PhilipGullick yes but nothing happens . also i dont want it to make MouseClick if its posible . i already add it on //rtb.MouseHover += new KeyEventHandler(rtb_MouseHover);
        //rtb.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(rtb_KeyUp); but nothing happens and i fail to that :| .

Comment: anyone pls? ...............